# Jquery + select the first ul of a menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have read several posts of this problem but I don't find the solution.

I have created a menu with 3 levels. I want to display the second & the third levels with a hover on the first level. For this I use the code:

```
$("#header ul.menu li").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find("ul").fadeTo('slow', 0.9);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find("ul").fadeOut('slow');
    }
);
```

It's ok and the submenu appears with a hover on the first level.

But, if I make a hover the second and the third level some ul children of the first ul, disappears.

How can I select only the first ul in my function? I have tried with several methods but without success :

```
$("#header ul.menu > li").hover(...
```

or

```
$(this).children("ul")....
```

Can you help me to resolve this problem?

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: Hello Razzildinho, i have created a fiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kumkum/SA2zw/24/. You can see my html code and css.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the :eq pseudo selector? http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

You can select any element using an index:

```
$('a:eq(0)')
```

The above will return the first `<a>` element on the page.

Comment: Hello athms, I have placed this code ($(this).find("ul:eq(0)").fadeTo('slow', 0.9); / $(this).find("ul:eq(0)").fadeOut('slow');) but the problem persist.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following method, it is working fine for me.

```
  $("ul.menu > li").hover(
            function(){
                $(this).find("ul").fadeTo('slow', 0.9);
            },
            function(){
                $(this).find("ul").fadeOut('slow');
            }
        );
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TPj2x/)

Comment: Hello Suresh Ponnukalai, thanks for your link. I have reproduced my problem in a fiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kumkum/SA2zw/23/. If I make a hover on the second level of the link 02, disapears the third level. Have you any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: Hello Suresh Ponnukalai, you have changed and delete the class on the second and third ul. But the menu is generated by Drupal and uls are automaticaly generated. I have found a solution and add a class on the first ul (answer above). I do not know if this is a good solution.

Comment: If that is the case, it is very simple. just check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SA2zw/26/

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, but it may not be clean. 
With JQuery, I add a class on the first ul.menu (nav).
Then I write this code:

```
            $(".menu-parent-wrapper > ul").addClass("nav");
            $("#header ul.nav > li").hover(
                function(){
                    $(this).find("ul").fadeTo('slow', 0.9);
                },
                function(){
                    $(this).find("ul").fadeOut('slow');
                }
            );
```

Now the menu is ok. The third level don't disapears when I make a hover on the items of the second level.

If you have another solution, you can post a new message.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SA2zw/27/) seems to do what you want.

I'm using jQuery's `children()` instead of `find()` as this prevents the secondary menus from being shown.